# Assign DOM element to object literal member

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm learning how one can achieve OOP patterns in JavaScript. I'd like to know, which one is a correct way to assign a DOM element to a object literal member in pure JavaScript and what are the differences between those examples.

I am doing this so that I could reuse that DOM element in object literal functions and if I change any id, name or class names, I only have to update in one place.

```
MyObject = {

    // Version 1
    member: document.getElementByName('elementName'),

    // Version 2
    member2: function() {

        return document.getElementByName('elementName');
    },

    // Version 3
    member3: function() {

        document.getElementByName('elementName');
    }

};

MyObject2 = {

    // Is this member in a different namespace
    member: document.getElementByName('element2Name'),
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> // Is this member in a different namespace
> member: document.getElementByName('element2Name'),
> ```

1. `MyObject2.member` and `MyObject1.member` are different. Javascript doesn't natively support namespace like in other languages but the same can be achieved using the Object literals.
2. Regarding the 3 different versions for the member assignment, the deciding factor is what kind of access do you need for your variable and how you want to consume that.

> ```
> // Version 1
> member: document.getElementsByName('elementName'),
> ```

This assigns the member property the result of the method `getElementsByName`, The result is a `NodeList` Collection. To access the property `member` you need to write it like `MyObject.member`.

> ```
> // Version 2
> member2: function() {
>
>     return document.getElementByName('elementName');
> },
> ```

The member2 is a `function`, whereas `member` wasn't a function and hence how the invocation is done is different. In this case you can get the same result as the version1 by calling `MyObject.member2()`.

> ```
> // Version 3
> member3: function() {
>
>     document.getElementByName('elementName');
> }
> ```

Version 3 doesn't **return** anything and is useless if you need to consume the result.  Basically, this version never stores the result of the function call `document.getElementByName('elementName');` and hence the return value is undefined. Like `member2`, `member3` is also a function. But, invoking the `function`  `MyObject.member3()` returns `undefined`.

**Which version to choose**

version 3 is **useless** as it doesn't return anything.

I do not have enough information of your application to suggest you best match. Based on limited information available, I would prefer version 2 because of the following reasons

- Since the value of the result which is defined by `document.getElementByName('elementName');` changes and is dependent on DOM. So, i will go ahead with the member2 or version2. i generally prefer function whenever it's not simple and involve some computation. Also, the result of the function call gives the caller information that the result of function call can change. Properties are good when you can define simple data attribute.

**Note:** A property's value can be a function, in which case the property is known as a method.

Comment: @Agalo- Now if I'd like to use one of those inside MyObject, then I can use meber1 like: this.member1. But what about member2?

Comment: Which member do you want to access and where ?

Comment: @Agalo- in MyObject I have a function that uses `this.member[0].onclick=function() { /* do something here */};` and then again with `this.member[1].onclick=function() {/* do something here as well*/};`

Comment: `this.member2()[0].onclick=function() { /* do something here */};` and then again with `this.member2()[1].onclick=function() {/* do something here as well*/};` Note the `()` after `member2`

Comment: you can call `MyObject2 = { login: function() {  MyObject.member2()  ;}};`

Comment: @Agalo- and in `MyObject2 = { login: function(argument) { /* do smth here too */;}};` and initialize it like `MyObject2.login(member);`

Comment: Please clearly ask your question, i am not sure what you are trying to accomplish, please edit your question if you need more information.